# Cannot fetch input value using jquery

Tags: ajax

index.php

function delete_function(value){

```
     alert("value is "+value);
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $.ajax({
                
                url: "fields.php",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "html",
                
                
                data: { "delval": value},
                    
                    success: function(data){
                        //console.log(data);
                         //jQuery(".res").html(data);
                        // var result = $(data).filter('div.dummy');
                         
                      //$(".dummy").append($(data).filter('div.dummy'));
                      var input_value = $(data).find("#lastname").val();
                      alert(input_value);
                      //$(data) = "dfsadf";
                     $(".dummy").replaceWith($(data).find('#lab').val());
                     //$(".dummy").replaceWith($(data).val());
                      //$(".dummy").replaceWith($(data).find('#submit').val());
                     // $(".dummy").remove();
                      //alert(data);
                      $(".class"+value).remove();
                    }
});
     
 
 
 alert("delete clicked ");
  });
  }
```

fields.php

" value="iamkarthik">
" value=  id="firstname"  placeholder="First Name">
" placeholder="Last Name">
" placeholder="Email address">
" placeholder="Department">
" placeholder="Date of joining">
" placeholder="Basic pay">
"  onclick="delete_function()" id="delete" value="delete" class="input_fields" >

Answer (score 0):

on delete function, please remove the $(document).ready , as this is event listener, it isn't triggered when you call the function

```
function delete_function(value){
    alert("value is "+value);

    $.ajax({
        url: "fields.php",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "html",
        data: { "delval": value},
        success: function(data){
            //console.log(data);
                //jQuery(".res").html(data);
            // var result = $(data).filter('div.dummy');

            //$(".dummy").append($(data).filter('div.dummy'));
            var input_value = $(data).find("#lastname").val();
            alert(input_value);
            //$(data) = "dfsadf";
            $(".dummy").replaceWith($(data).find('#lab').val());
            //$(".dummy").replaceWith($(data).val());
            //$(".dummy").replaceWith($(data).find('#submit').val());
            // $(".dummy").remove();
            //alert(data);
            $(".class"+value).remove();
        }
    });
    
    alert("delete clicked ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks ahmed. But still it is not triggering